# Define a database entry in DB2 db2dsdriver.cfg file that can access multiple databases

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I currently use the CLI method of registering a node and then a database for that node (with CATALOG NODE / CATALOG DATABASE) to configure my DB2 CLI client to access our database server.

With a single registration of a database I can effectively register the default database but then when I connect in my application using SQLDriverConnect and use the "DATABASE=" option I can connect to other databases available on my server.

I would like to switch to the much easier to manage `db2dsdriver.cfg` configuration file, however I have been unable to configure it to allow a single  to access multiple databases.

Some code to help clarify. My DB2 server instance has two databases defined like:

```
CREATE DATABASE DB_1 ON /opt/data/DB_1 USING CODESET UTF-8 TERRITORY US COLLATE USING SYSTEM
CREATE DATABASE DB_2 ON /opt/data/DB_2 USING CODESET UTF-8 TERRITORY US COLLATE USING SYSTEM
```

I register this server with my client CLI using these commands:

```
CATALOG TCPIP NODE DB_NODE remote example.server.com server 50000
CATALOG DB DB_1 as DB_1 at node DB_NODE
```

With that setup I can perform the following from my CLI application:

```
rc = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, "DSN=DB_1;UID=dbtest1;PWD=zebco5;DATABASE=DB_1",
    SQL_NTS, outStr, 128, &outSize, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
```

or if I want to use the DB_2 database:

```
rc = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, "DSN=DB_1;UID=dbtest1;PWD=zebco5;DATABASE=DB_2",
    SQL_NTS, outStr, 128, &outSize, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
```

Note I did not need to change the DSN, merely the "DATABASE" connection option.

Recently I found the `db2dsdriver.cfg` configuration file which I would rather use. To that end I created this and uncataloged my node and db from the cli:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<configuration>
  <dsncollection>
    <dsn alias="DB_1" name="DB_1" host="server.example.com" port="50000"/>
  </dsncollection>
  <databases>
    <database name="DB_1" host="server.example.com" port="50000"/>
    <database name="DB_2" host="server.example.com" port="50000"/>
  </databases>
</configuration>
```

I can connect with this:

```
rc = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, "DSN=DB_1;UID=dbtest1;PWD=zebco5;DATABASE=DB_1",
    SQL_NTS, outStr, 128, &outSize, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
```

just fine, but now using this to connect to DB_2:

```
rc = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, "DSN=DB_1;UID=dbtest1;PWD=zebco5;DATABASE=DB_2",
    SQL_NTS, outStr, 128, &outSize, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
```

results in this error:

```
SQL0843N  The server name does not specify an existing connection.  SQLSTATE=08003
```

Which I understand, but seems like a regression in functionality from the old node/db registration mechanism.

I'm attempting to determine if the functionality I was using is supported with the configuration file and I am doing something wrong or if it just doesn't work that way?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "a single to access multiple databases"? What do you mean by "unable"? What does your current configuration file look like? What errors do you get?

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify.  Thank you.

Comment: Which version (i.e. which db2level) of which Db2-client variant lets   the DATABASE property override  the DSN property in the connection string for the SQLDriverConnect?  For my v11.1 Db2-client on Windows the SQLDriverConnect ignores the DATABASE= value and connects to the specified DSN only.  Are you quite certain the connection is really to DB_2 when DSN=DB_1 ?

Comment: You are correct, I hadn't picked up that while the connection was being allowed setting `DATABASE=` wasn't actually switching my login to DB_2. I'll need to go have a re-read on the documentation. Thanks!